# Binary file got corrupted after packaging

Tags: yum, rpm, rpmbuild

A quick overview, what I'm doing is bundling a nodejs application using [enclose.js](http://enclosejs.com) into a single binary, then using `rpmbuild` to turn the whole project with config files into a single package. Everything is fine before packaging but there's a binary file that gets corrupted after the result rpm is installed. That file is a 40MB binary while the rpm is 52MB but after installation the binary extracted is only 15MB.

This is my spec file:

```
Name: Packager
Version: 2.0
Release: 0
License: Proprietary
Group: System/Extras
Distribution: Linux CentOS
Packager: Ammar Lakis <ammar.lakis@gmail.com>
Requires: mongodb-server
Summary: A quick packager

%description
Package made for packaging

%build
cd %{my_source}
npm run build

%install
cp -r %{my_source}/pkg/ $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%post
systemctl enable packager

%files
/usr/bin/packager
/usr/bin/packager-tools
/etc/packager
```

and the building process is done with this command

```
rpmbuild -bb --define 'my_source /root/Packager/' packager.spec
```

Is there anything causing the truncating of the bundled files  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, rpmbuild strips binaries and libraries (using `/usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress`) after they have been placed in the rpm file.  You should be able to disable this by adding to the start of your spec file

```
%global __os_install_post %{nil}
```

Comment: Yeah, i got bit by this too.  a couple things:

1) technically brp-compress is not the issue, it just compresses man pages. But __os_install_post does a lot more

2) do rpmbuild --showrc > /tmp/rpmbuild_showrc.txt to see all that it does.  /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip does the strip, but it also repackages static libs, jar files, and some other things.